# CPP - Convert source code from Windows to Linux

Tags: c++, linux, windows

I have a single-file CPP app, built for Windows and is running in command line only.

I am trying to make it compilable also for Linux.

The only libraries the app is using are:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "setjmp.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include "time.h"
```

It also uses all kinds of unsigned integers (uint8, uint16, uint32, uint64).

Other than this there aren't any other Windows-specific APIs.

My question is how to convert the code so it will be compatible with Linux?
Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Why are you using SJLJ in C++?

Comment: This is too broad because `windows.h` contains almost most of the winapis. You need exact source to get an answer.

Comment: All the headers you show are system headers and should use angle-brackets `<>`.

Comment: *"Is there an easy way to do this?"* - No.

Comment: And what is your application doing ?

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi, I have the code. It is not mine - it just works. I don't want to change anything, just to be able to run it in Ubuntu command line (without wine).

Comment: My simple 2-step process will do it: 1) remove Windows-specific headers. 2) fix the compile errors.

Answer (score 1):

Do it the other way round. Code, probably using some cross-platform framework like [Poco](http://pocoproject.org) or [Qt](http://qt.io/) (which is also usable in non-GUI code, e.g. using [QtCore](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcore-index.html) *without* [QtGui](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtgui-index.html)), or [Boost](http://www.boost.org/), in some Windows independent way and compile it regularly on *both* OSes.

BTW `setjmp.h`  is C++ unfriendly (messing and incompatible with C++ exceptions), even on Windows.

So remove

```
#include "setjmp.h" /// wrong in all C++ programs
#include "windows.h"  //// specific to Windows
```

then fix the code (e.g. all compilation errors; but on Linux compile with all warnin & debug info, e.g. with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`), probably using some framework like the ones I mentioned.

Don't *convert* C++ code (from Windows to Linux) but do try hard to write *portable* C++ code, thanks to some well chosen framework.

Perhaps your application could be written in some pure portable C++11 (but then, no need to `#include "windows.h"`). Command-line utilities like `wc`, `cat`, `grep` (with a subset of all features) could probably be written in portable C++11 -and might not even require any additional framework.

PS. Without having your source code and without any idea about what that application is, it is impossible to help you more. Your first task is to understand that code precisely and what it is supposed to do on Windows. Perhaps rewriting it in clean C++11 (maybe with some additional framework....) is the quickest way to do it.

Comment: The program is written in Visual CPP. I don't want to rewrite it, unless I have no other option.

Comment: You won't need to *rewrite* all of it. You just need to recode those things that to fail be compiled. For some reasonably clean code, that should be reasonably easy. But `"setjmp.h"` is wrong in C++ even on Windows, so I guess your code is quite messy and buggy (even on Windows).

Comment: I wish it was my code - It would have saved me a lot of headache. This is an old code from somebody who is not working anymore in my company and now I am required to compile it for Linux (wine is not an option).

Comment: But you need to understand that code and have a precise idea of what it is doing (on Windows). Perhaps the code is so messy that rewriting it from scratch, using some portable framework, is the quickest way to get the job done